# Can someone tell me what im doing wrong? it keeps saying meal_cost is not defined

Tags: python

```
def solve(meal_cost, tip_percent, tax_percent):
    # Write your code here
    meal_cost = float(input())
    tip_percent = int(input())
    tax_percent = int(input())
    
    tip = meal_cost*tip_percent/100
    tax = meal_cost*tax_percent/100
    total_cost = meal_cost + tip + tax
    
    print(round(total_cost))
    
solve(meal_cost, tip_percent, tax_percent)
```

Comment: Why are you passing things in as arguments when you then assign them from `input()`?

Comment: When you run `solve(meal_cost, ...)`, there's expected to _already exist_ a `meal_cost` variable. Just take it out of the argument list if you don't need to pass it in as an argument.

Comment: (better, though, is to move the `input()`s outside the function; that way the function can be called getting its input from other sources instead).

Answer (score 2):

When you call `solve`, you have not defined any of the parameters you pass.
The solution is to define them:

```
def solve(meal_cost, tip_percent, tax_percent):
    # Write your code here
    meal_cost = float(input())
    tip_percent = int(input())
    tax_percent = int(input())
    
    tip = meal_cost*tip_percent/100
    tax = meal_cost*tax_percent/100
    total_cost = meal_cost + tip + tax
    
    print(round(total_cost))
    


meal_cost = 3.0
tip_percentage = 0.19
tax_percent = 0.1
solve(meal_cost, tip_percent, tax_percent)
```

Note that this will overwrite the values passed in because you then ask to `input` the actual values. You can do this instead:

```
def solve(meal_cost, tip_percent, tax_percent):
    tip = meal_cost*tip_percent/100
    tax = meal_cost*tax_percent/100
    total_cost = meal_cost + tip + tax
    
    print(round(total_cost))
    
meal_cost = float(input())
tip_percent = int(input())
tax_percent = int(input())
solve(meal_cost, tip_percent, tax_percent)
```

as pointed out by Charles in the comment.

Comment: Those numbers will just be ignored, overwritten by the output of an `float(input())` or `int(input())` call. You might as well say `meal_cost = tip_percentage = tax_percent = None` if you aren't going to direct the OP to remove the arguments from the list outright or stop overwriting them with input-derived values.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy sure, but that's a different bug not related to the actual question.

Comment: I disagree that it's unrelated. The OP's misunderstandings are correlated here; if they understood what a parameter _is_ and what it's for, they might not have chosen to make their function take any arguments at all. Or they might have chosen to put the input collection _outside_ the function instead of inside it.

Comment: I edited my answer after you edited your comment.